# Dynamic onclick isn't working in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've this block of code in my js file. When the user mouseover the last div block, I'm adding a + and delete button which is working fine in firefox. But not in chrome.

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '.item-block-row', function(){
        if($(this).closest('#glaceblock').length || $(this).closest('#sorbetblock').length){
            $('.deleteSorbGlaceItem').remove();

            if($(this).is(':last-child')){
                var maximumCount = 10;
                if($('.layout-item-row').length >= maximumCount){
                    // Need to show only the delete icon for the last row
                    if($(this).closest('#sorbetblock').length){
                        $(this).append('<div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 deleteSorbGlaceItem" ><div class="deleteIcon" onclick="deleteMultipleItem(' + projectId + ', this); "><img title="Supprimer" class="action_button image-button-dimensions" src="images/Picto_poubelle.png" alt="Supprimer" ></div></div>');
                    } 
                    return;
                }

                if($(this).closest('#sorbetblock').length){
                    $(this).append('<div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 deleteSorbGlaceItem"><div class="addIcon" onclick="addItemBlock(' + projectId + ', \'editsorbet\', \'sorbet\');"><img title="Modifier le format" class="action_button image-button-dimensions" src="images/Picto_format.png" alt="format" ></div></div>');
                }

                if($(this).closest('#sorbetblock').length && $('#sorbetblock .sorbetitem').length <= 4){
                    // If row item is last and only 2 rows exists  adding only '+' button for adding an item .
                    // do nothing

                }   
                else {  
                     // If row item is last adding '+',' delete'  
                    if($(this).closest('#sorbetblock').length){
                        $(this).find('.deleteSorbGlaceItem').append('<div class="deleteIcon" onclick="deleteMultipleItem(' + projectId + ', this); "><img title="Supprimer" class="action_button image-button-dimensions" src="images/Picto_poubelle.png" alt="Supprimer" ></div>');    
                    } 
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

I understand that `onclick` for dynamic element will not work in chrome, so the solution is to use on click frunction from `jquery`. So I tried this.

```
$(document).on('click', '.addIcon', function(){
    console.log('t');
});
```

and this isn't working at all in chrome but fine in firefox. I've been working with jquery click and onclick for more than 2 years. I never faced this issue in chrome.

Anything wrong int he code or did I miss anything ?

Edit:

I removed the inline `onclick="addItemBlock(' + projectId + ', \'editglace\', \'glace\');"` when I tried the jquery onclick.

Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qubfcc7z/9/)

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle?

Comment: I'm doing it now

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qubfcc7z/9/

Comment: @SmitRaval Fiddle is there

Comment: What exactly is failing? The entire script? Or just the click handler?

Comment: Why do you bind the `click` event on the parent `div` and not the image itself?

Comment: You can see that the alert is working on the firefox but not on the chrome

Comment: @Sabbin because the image size is too small so the user has to click exactly on it. Div size is little big. That's the reason

Comment: @djfdev Did you notice that ?

Comment: Yes I just noticed that. Can you provide the callback definitions as well?

Comment: What do you mean by callback definition here ?

Comment: `deleteMutlipleItem` and `addItemBlock`

Comment: You can see the fiddle. addItemBlock is removed in the onlcick.

Comment: deleteMutlipleItem isn't used at the moment at all. The issue isn't with any of those functions, its with firing the click event in chrome. It is not firing at the moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check with this: https://jsfiddle.net/qubfcc7z/34/

The problem is: function $(document).on('mouseover', '.item-block-row' is run a lot of time

```
if(($(this).closest('#glaceblock').length || $(this).closest('#sorbetblock').length) && $(this).find('.deleteSorbGlaceItem').length ===0){
```

Comment: Well, that's the functionality of the `mouseover`. I'm clearing it by `$('.deleteSorbGlaceItem').remove()`. Is this multiple calls an issue ?

Comment: You can check the DOM element. $('.deleteSorbGlaceItem') is reload a lot of time because the mouseover event

Comment: I agree, but how this will prevent the onclick event from firing ?

Comment: Your suggestion is working. Thanks a lot. I handled that now. But I'm trying to understand the issue

Comment: In this case, Try to bind onclick and append to the parent instead of use document.click

Answer (score 1):

from : https://api.jquery.com/mouseover/

> The mouseover event is sent to an element when the mouse pointer
>   enters the element.

this means that the code is executed non-stop while the mouse is over the element, therefore creating and removing the image quickly leaving no room for the `click` event , a simple `console.log('here')` inside the function can demonstrate that :

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '.item-block-row', function(){
    console.log('here');
```

this can consume a lot of resources and slowing your website,

so replacing it with `$(document).on('mouseenter', '.item-block-row', function(){ ...` will solve your problem as the code will be executed only once when the mouse enters the element, https://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/

Comment: Thanks!! It is helpful

Comment: you're welcome, i saw @Tan beat me to an answer when i posted it so i deleted it, but you wanted to understand the issue so i undeleted the post hoping this will help :)